# Infinite loop to poll on a modified file and write its contents to a new file in C

Tags: c, file, infinite

I am new to C programming and am trying to execute the code below.

My objective is to create a program that continuously polls on an input file, reads it when it is modified and writes the contents to a new output file.

The program writes to the output file if there is no 'while(1)' loop but it doesn't write to the output file (though the contents have been read) in the infinite loop. Could you please guide me where I am wrong?

```
void main(){
    struct stat time_buf;
    time_t input_timestamp=0;

    while(1){
        if(access( "inpfile.txt", F_OK ) != -1){
            sleep(5);
            stat("inpfile.txt", &time_buf);
            if(time_buf.st_mtime > input_timestamp){
                FILE *fpi,*fpo;
                long length;
                char *buffer=0;           
                fpi = fopen("inpfile.txt","r");
                fseek(fpi,0,SEEK_END);
                length=ftell(fpi);
                fseek(fpi,0,SEEK_SET);
                buffer=(char *)malloc(length);
                fread(buffer,1,length,fpi);
                fclose(fpi);      

                fpo=fopen("outfile.txt","w+");
                fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),length,fpo);
                fclose(fpo);
                input_timestamp=time_buf.st_mtime;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: All I know is that you should be using `int main()` instead of `void main()`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are the values in the variables what you expected them to be?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging using GDB (step by step) and it works fine as expected. But, direct execution of program isn't working.

Comment: Not using your file system change notification events could be one 'wrong'.

Answer (score 1):

None of this is really going to answer your problem directly, since you don't really state anything other than your code isn't working.  What do you think a car mechanic would ask you if you told him, "My car isn't working."

For example, you're not telling us if the modification time reported by your call to `stat()` changes when you think the file contents change.

- First, the call to `access()` is worse than useless:

  ```
  if(access( "inpfile.txt", F_OK ) != -1){
     .
     .
     .
  ```

  That call does you no good, and it introduces the possibility of [a TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).  Just open the file - don't check if it exists first.  If it doesn't exist, opening the file will fail with an `ENOENT` or similar value in `errno`.

  Trying to somehow check if something you plan to do later will work is almost always a bad idea.  "I want to check if the file exists before I try to open it." or "I want to ping the server to make sure it's alive before I try to connect to it."  are **BAD IDEAS**.  They not only introduce a race condition if the situation changes between the check and the action (what happens if the file is deleted between your `access()` call and the `fopen()` call?), the *check* has to differ from your intended *action* in some way otherwise it would *be* the action.  And since it's different, different rules apply.  A fully-functional server may be configured to not respond to pings, for example.  So the check can fail in situations where the action itself would actually work.  And the other way around - the check can work and then the action can fail.

  Don't *check*.  Just *do*.  And then handle all errors.
- Second, since you're using `stat()` to get the file's modification time, there's no need to use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of the file as there's an `st_size` field in `struct stat` that tells you the file size.

  This will copy a file in one step (note that there's no error checking at all, and I used `open()`/`read()`/`write()` instead of `fopen()`/`fread()`/`fwrite()` since you're already using POSIX functions - that allows using `fstat()` on the file descriptor instead of `stat()` on the input file name, meaning that name only has to be used once:

  ```
  struct stat sb;
  int fd = open( inputFileName, O_RDONLY );
  fstat( fd, &sb );
  char *data = malloc( sb.st_size );
  read( fd, data, sb.st_size );
  close( fd );
  fd = open( outputFileName, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644 );
  write( fd, data, sb.st_size );
  close( fd );
  free( data );
  ```

  Note that there is no error checking in that code - `open()` can fail, `malloc()` can fail, `read()` and `write()` can both be only partially successful (try to write 8 KB, and only 4 KB actually get written), so **you have to check return values**.  I also left out all the necessary header files.

  Adapting that code to a loop where you check for a change in the modification time shouldn't be hard.
- Third, technically `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of the file is undefined behavior in C. (I have no idea why it's taught so much.  Bad teachers?  And if you use it on Windows on files > 2 GB you'll have issues as `long` is 32 bits even on 64-bit Windows.)

  Streams open in binary mode are not required to support `fseek(..., SEEK_END)` - footnote 268 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) specifically states "Setting  the  file  position  indicator  to  end-of-file,  as  with `fseek(file,  0,  SEEK_END)`,  has
  undefined behavior for a binary stream ...".  And `ftell()` on a text stream does not represent how many bytes will be read from a file.  Per **7.21.9.4  The `ftell` function**, paragraph 2:

  > The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position
  >   indicator for the stream pointed  to  by `stream`. For  a  binary 
  >   stream,  the  value  is  the  number  of  characters  from the
  >   beginning of the file.  For a text stream, its file position indicator
  >   contains unspecified information, usable by the `fseek` function for
  >   returning the file position indicator for the stream  to  its 
  >   position  at  the  time  of  the `ftell` call;  the  difference 
  >   between  two  such return values is not necessarily a meaningful
  >   measure of the number of characters written or read.
- Fourth, you state "though the contents have been read", but from the posted code you can't know that - you don't check *any* return values.  You just make calls and *hope* they actually work.
- You're also at risk of having this question closed as off-topic.  One of the reasons for that is:

  > Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
  >   include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
  >   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
  >   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
  >   readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
  >   example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

  As one of the comments already noted, you didn't mention your debugging efforts.

And none of this answer gets into the difficulty of actually detecting file system changes and then processing the changed data.  It's not easy to do reliably and quickly, and it I'd say it indicates a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fflush` after the `fwrite`. 
The `fwrite` does not write the data into the real file it write it to a buffer stream and after X time it will update the data or if the stream buffer is full.

Comment: No.  The call to `fclose()` in the posted code will flush the buffer.